# Access Model Property In Laravel Mutators

Tags: laravel, mutators

I want to convert `created_at` dates to Persian date. So I implemented `getCreatedAtAttribute` function to do that. Because I just want to convert dates in special situations, I declared `$convert_dates` property in the model with default value as `false`.

```
class Posts extends Model {
    public $convert_dates = false;

    /**
     * Always capitalize the first name when we retrieve it
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
        return $this->convert_dates? convert_date($value): $value;
    }
}

$Model = new Posts;
$Model->convert_dates = true;

$post = $Model->first();

echo $post->created_at; // Isn't converted because $convert_dates is false
```

As you see in the codes above, it seems the model properties will be re-initial in mutators so the value of `$convert_dates` is always `false`.

Is there any other trick or solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Set a constructor to set the value of `convert_dates`

Answer (score 0):

This way you can set the constructor.

```
public function __construct($value = null, array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->convert_dates = $value;

    parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Now you can access this value in your mutator.

```
 public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) 
 {
    return $this->convert_dates ? convert_date($value) : $value;
 }
```

**OR**

Fill the protected fillable array like this:

```
class DataModel extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $fillable = array('convert_dates');
}
```

Then initialize the Model as:

```
$dataModel = new DataModel(array(
    'convert_dates' => true
));
```

Comment: $post = Posts::first();
$post->converted_dates = true;

Comment: @Omid : Did you try this?

Comment: `$post = Posts::first();` and `dd($post->converted_dates = true);`
Do you see the new attribute appended to the model?